# Index out of range while converting file from csv to xml

Tags: python, python-2.7

While running the following code for converting csv to xml I'm getting index out of range error.

I used the code below a small subset of file with 16 columns it works fine but when I try it on more than 30 its giving following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "csv2xml.py", line 40, in <module>
    + rowData[i] + '</' + tags[i] + '>' + "\n")
IndexError: list index out of range
```

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys 
import os 
import glob 

delimiter = "," # "\t" "|" # delimiter used in the CSV file(s) 


# the optional command-line argument maybe a CSV file or a folder 
if len(sys.argv) == 2: 
    arg = sys.argv[1].lower() 
    if arg.endswith('.csv'): # if a CSV file then convert only that file 
        csvFiles = [arg] 
    else: # if a folder path then convert all CSV files in the that folder 
        os.chdir(arg) 
        csvFiles = glob.glob('*.csv') 
# if no command-line argument then convert all CSV files in the current folder 
elif len(sys.argv) == 1: 
    csvFiles = glob.glob('*.csv') 
else: 
    os._exit(1) 


for csvFileName in csvFiles: 
    xmlFile = csvFileName[:-4] + '.xml' 
    # read the CSV file as binary data in case there are non-ASCII characters 
    csvFile = open(csvFileName, 'rb') 
    csvData = csvFile.readlines() 
    csvFile.close() 
    tags = csvData.pop(0).strip().replace(' ', '_').split(delimiter) 
    xmlData = open(xmlFile, 'w') 
    xmlData.write('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>' + "\n") 
    # there must be only one top-level tag 
    xmlData.write('<CTS>' + "\n") 
    for row in csvData: 
        rowData = row.strip().split(delimiter) 
        xmlData.write('<Product>' + "\n") 
        for i in range(len(tags)): 
            xmlData.write('    ' + '<' + tags[i] + '>'  
                          + rowData[i] + '</' + tags[i] + '>' + "\n") 
        xmlData.write('</Product>' + "\n")                 
    xmlData.write('</CTS>' + "\n") 
    xmlData.close()
```

Comment: It looks like your `rowData` list is not as wide as your `tags` list. Perhaps you need to validate them.

Comment: thanks for your response @quamrana can you help me fix it

Comment: What should happen when a line of data is not as wide as the column headers?

Comment: it should just add a blank entry

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your for loop over the lines of data should check the length of `rowData` like this:

```
tags_length = len(tags)
for row in csvData: 
    rowData = row.strip().split(delimiter) 
    xmlData.write('<Product>' + "\n") 
    if len(rowData) >= tags_length:
        for i in range(tags_length): 
            xmlData.write('    ' + '<' + tags[i] + '>'  
                          + rowData[i] + '</' + tags[i] + '>' + "\n") 
    xmlData.write('</Product>' + "\n")
```